# Image warping algorithm with a specified vector as distortion direction

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I'm studying image warping and I'm unsure how I would proceed to do a simple image warping by specifying something like a direction vector, as in the following picture:

[image]

([image reference](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr11/cos426/notes/cos426_s11_lecture03_warping.pdf))

What's the algorithm to do that?

Here's what I thought and here's the question:

I believe a vector should be specified if I want to distort the image as above: the source pixel will go in the vector specified position, but **how do the "surrounding pixels" follow that point?**

Comment: Linear or bilinear interpolation. You know the starting and ending position of each pixel, and so you can interpolate between two points in the *source* image and apply the same value in the *output* image. Bit broad for SO, to be honest.

Comment: @Jongware so there's a function to do the reverse mapping even for such a distortion? I really can't see it